# Use radio button to change name of another element

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button

How can I use radio buttons to change the name of the text area tag below. Im trying to allow users to choose if they want to enter in an item_id or a upc, and based on this selection, the param for the text area should change.

What I have so far:

```
<label for="item_ids">Item Ids</label>
<input type="radio" name="=type_radio" id="item_ids" value="<%=params['item_ids']%>">
<label for="upcs">Upc Numbers </label>
<input type="radio" name="type_radio" id="upcs" value="<%=params['upcs']%>">

<textarea rows="3" type="text" name="<either item_ids OR upcs" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" placeholder="separated by space or comma"><%=params['item_ids_upcs']%></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $('textarea').attr('name', $(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```